# PasteSpecial function not copying date - VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am working on a VSTO addin where I am trying to copy the values of one sheet to another but pasted as text only. In excel I can manually open a new sheet, set the cells to text format, and copy the data over. I'm trying to do this programmatically. Here is some code:

```
    Worksheet currentSheet; // This is the sheet I'm copying from
    Excel.Range currentRange = currentSheet.Cells.Application.Selection.SpecialCells(
                                 Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible,
                                 Type.Missing);

    Excel.Worksheet newWorksheet; // This is the sheet I'm copyng to
    newWorksheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"; // set the format of cells to text

    currentRange.Copy(); // Copy the data
    newWorksheet.Range["A1"].PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteValues,
    XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone,
    System.Type.Missing,
    System.Type.Missing);
```

This works okay, however, sometimes the data that I'm copying from will contain dates (e.g. 2019-10-01) and when I copy it over to the new sheet it ends up as a number even though I'm using `XlPasteType.xlPasteValues` I just want the text value brought across into the new cell. Is this possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick test here shows that `PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats)` retains the *text* formatting of a cell.

Or, apply the formatting *after* pasting:

```
newWorksheet.Range["A1"].PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteValues,
  XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone,
  System.Type.Missing,
  System.Type.Missing);
newWorksheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "@";
```

FWIW I don't see date formatting turned into number formatting, explicitly. I see the cell formatting applied already to the target cell. In my case, it was "general".

Comment: Thanks. "XlPasteType.xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats" worked a treat.